# How to fix "add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path" error for submodule on rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

My project structure looks like this:

```
Parent repository (PR)
   - Child submodule 1 (S1)
   - Child submodule 2 (S2)
   - Child submodule 3 (S3)
```

When I want to rebase my parent repository it shows the following message:

```
Could not apply 53e9728... update submodules
Fast-forwarding submodule S1
Auto-merging S1
error: add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path 'path/to/submodule'; merge aborting.
```

The problem **only** occurs when I try to rebase it. If I merge the branch to other branch it works fine!

I tried to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57199694/713847) (changed core.autocrlf to false) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63057163/713847) (removed my branch and then pulled again from origin), but none of the solution fixed my issue. Is there any other way to fix the problem?

---

Edit: the problem occurs with one specific commit. I tried to cherry-pick that particular commit and the same error message showed up.

---

Edit 2: I ended up removing the commit from history. For me it was an option, but for others it may not be.

For future reference:

```
git rebase -i <commit id of the previous commit that needs to be deleted>

drop commit
```

Comment: The `core.autocrlf` setting should not really affect this. It's not clear to me why rebase is showing this problem, which isn't something ordinary users should ever see in the first place.

Comment: @torek: this is first time I have experienced this problem. I took the suggestion from one of the suggestions I added above. What puzzles me even more that it behaves differently for rebase and merge

Comment: Re the edit: that part makes sense. There is something about that particular commit that gets Git bollixed up internally. What it is, is not clear; with a reproducer, it can probably be debugged and fixed. (The "aborting" should not happen; at worst, you should get a complaint that requires some sort of manual resolution, like a standard merge conflict.)

Comment: @torek I ended up removing the commit from history. For me it was an option, but for others it may not be.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message for a submodule with a new commit inside of the submodule. Simply committing the new hash of the submodule on the parent repository fixed it for me.